# Transfer 2-10MB files with WCF to non .Net clients

Tags: wcf, delphi, soap

There are a lot of posts about transferring files through WCF, and most of them recommend streaming. I'm designing a WCF service that will have several different clients, .Net and non .Net (Delphi 2010 clients), downloading those files. What is the best method to transfer files when there will be non .Net clients?
**Edit**
I will be transferring the files through the internet via basicHttpBinding
Tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use the MTOM encoding for binary data. It is the preferred way of passing data between compatible clients.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751889.aspx

Comment: AFAIK the implementation of Soap 1.2 in Delphi including 2010 does not support MTOM. https://forums.codegear.com/message.jspa?messageID=308342

Comment: @mjn, do you know if Delphi XE is?

Comment: The feature matrix does not mention it, and the additional third-party SOAP library introduced in XE seems to be still on Soap 1.1 level